isomorphic groups that are G-equivariant
Start with two finite groups $A$ and $B$ and a group isomorphism $f$ between them. Let a finite group $G$ act on both $A$ and $B$. By definition $f$ is $G$-equivariant if $g(f(a))=f(g(a))$. Do I understand correctly that I have to know precisely what the action of $G$ on both $A$ and $B$ looks like to decide whether $f$ is $G$-equivariant?
Assume I would like for $f$ to be $G$-equivariant for a given $G$. Considering that I can choose different actions of $G$, how can I evaluate if one of them on $A$ and one of them on $B$ result in a $G$-equivariant isomorphism $f$?
Edit: As Julio rephrased, what I would like to know is given a $G$-set $(A,\rho_A)$ and an isomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$, does there exist a group action $\rho_B$ on $B$ making $f$ $G$-equivariant (or the reverse)? If yes, how do I continue?

I'm not sure I think I'm confused. First of all: I would like to find out if for two isomorphic groups I can see if they are G-equivariant. But there are lots of possible actions of G on both A and B, so do I need to construct them all (probably not possible) to figure out if we have a G-equivariant group isomorphism. OR: Do I only need one action of G on A and B that I need to examine together with f? Sorry, as I said I am confused.

What do you mean by a group action here?  Do you just mean that $G$ acts on $A,B$ as finite sets or something else?  And...if we don't know what the $G$ actions are, what do we know about them?

A $G$-set is the data of both a set $A$ and a group action $\rho: G \to \mathfrak{S} (A)$. The action is included in the definition, now maybe you are asking given a $G$-set $(A,\rho_A)$ and a map $f:A \to B$, does there exist a group action $\rho_B$ on $B$ making $f$ $G$-equivariant (or the reverse)? Also for groups you have two usual actions: left multiplication and conjugation. They are obviously both preserved by isomorphisms, hence your iso is equivariant for the actions by left multiplication and for the actions by conjugation.

@julio_es_sui_glace yes, I think that is what I'm asking. Let me edit my question. Thank you!

The answer is yes, just consider the trivially defined action:
$$\rho_B (g)  = f \circ \rho_A (g) \circ f^{-1} $$
basically $g\cdot b := f(g\cdot f^{-1}(a))$. This is a group action since
$$\begin{align*}
\rho_B(g) \circ \rho_B(g') &= f \circ \rho_A (g) \circ f^{-1}\circ f \circ \rho_A (g') \circ f^{-1} \\
&= f \circ \rho_A (g) \circ \rho_A(g')\circ f^{-1} \\
&= f \circ \rho_A (gg') \circ f^{-1} \\
&= \rho_B(gg')
\end{align*}$$
Now $f$ is obviously equivariant since for $g \in G$,
$$\rho_B(g) \circ f = f \circ \rho_A (g) \circ f^{-1} \circ f = f \circ \rho_A(g)$$
In fact, this is the only possible action for $f$ to be equivariant you can show that on your own.

You may want to consider the case where $f$ is not an iso, then you have $B = f(A) \sqcup C$. You action can be anything on $C$ but it is more complicated on $f(A)$. Notice that if you have a suitable action on $B$, if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $f(g\cdot x) = g \cdot f(x) = g \cdot f(y) = f(g\cdot y)$, so $f$ must verify the property:
$$\forall g \in G, \, x,y \in A, \, f(x) = f(y) \implies f(g\cdot x) = f(g\cdot y)$$
If so any suitable group action for $f$ to be equivariant verifies $g\cdot f(x) := f(g\cdot x)$ And if $C$ is finite, the restriction of $\rho_B$ to $C$ is a group action. But one can in any case define a suitable action by:
$$g \cdot f(x) = f(g\cdot x)$$
$$\forall c \in C, \, g \cdot c = c$$

@tess If so please accept the answer so that it can be filed by the site
